# Promise error in ionic code 3, 4 TypeError: Cannot read property 'nomeCategoria' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I get an error in my code when I try to register a product on my list.

Follow my code:
 ## Carrega todos os dados da categoria passada por parâmentro ##############

```
 public getAll(categoria: string) {
    let produtos: ListaProduto[] = [];
    let arrProduto: ListaProduto[] = [];


    return this.storage
      .forEach((value: Produto, key: string) => {
        let produto = new ListaProduto();
        produto.key = key;
        produto.produto = value;
        produtos.push(produto);
    enter code here
      })

      .then(() => {

        // ## Filtro dos produto pela categoria passada no parametro
        arrProduto = produtos.filter(value => {
          return value.produto.categoriaItem.nomeCategoria === categoria;
        });

        return Promise.resolve(arrProduto);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        return Promise.reject(arrProduto);
      });
  }
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'nomeCategoria' of undefined
    at product-storage.ts:96
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at product-storage.ts:95
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at polyfills.js:3
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)
```

Can you help me please

Comment: Hi Thoth, please paste your code into the question so users do not need to leave the Stack Overflow site to read/answer your question.

Comment: Done.
Thanks for the tip

Comment: Now its just a waiting game. I am not familiar with what you posted myself, but SO will keep your question visible until you have at least one answer attempt (comments like this not included). You might also try reposting the question as well, considering you have made a major edit to it. Typically I will have a few questions open myself at any one time, that way I can move to other parts of my app while stews waiting for an answer. Good luck!

Comment: What is `this.storage`? Ionic storage or a variable?

Comment: It is a Ionic storage